# How would I hook into `clear_auth_cookie` to return the user's ID that's currently being logged out?

Tags: users, logout

`clear_auth_cookie` is what I'd need in order to catch the actual logout action, but I can't get it to return anything.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L940

As per the Codex, it doesn't give any information.

Ideally I'd like to do:

```
add_action( 'clear_auth_cookie', 'return_user_data_on_logout');

function return_user_data_on_logout( $user ) {
    $id = $user->ID; //Assuming it returns a WP_User object.
    //Do some logic here, mostly to check if the user if is of certain type     / 
    has certain meta attached to them.
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That action doesn't pass that data:

```
function return_user_data_on_logout( $user ) {
```

Here, `$user` will alway be undefined. Additionally, you need to tell `add_action` how many parameters the function takes.

But..

```
do_action( 'clear_auth_cookie' );
```

No information is passed to begin with, that's not how this particular event/action works.

So how do we get the current user being logged out? The answer is we remove the words "being logged out" from that question giving us a much easier question that is far more searchable:

How do we get the current user?

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
```

It's possible that this hook may be too early, and additionally it may not be the best hook to use.

For example, `wp_logout` is a much better hook to use as it says on the tin what it does

So:

```
add_action( 'wp_logout', function() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Works well, it's weird, I tried it before but I must've gotten lost in something that it didn't work.

Comment: When exactly should this fire in order to register? It seems that if I register it late, it just doesn't work.

Comment: That's a good question, and one you should ask, a comment won't do it justice

Comment: I tried this within a plugin. The call definitely happened, but the call to the get current user returns empty.

Comment: @DebbieKurth without more information it's not possible to diagnose what happened. You should ask a question and include the code you tried and as much detail as possible. My answer is intended only for the original question.

Comment: I found the solution, two ways.  See below

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and another individual gave me a second and better solution.  That dialogue can be found here:
[Getting User email on logout. wp_logout](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/387793/getting-user-email-on-logout-wp-logout/387796#387796)

Here the two solutions:

SOLUTION 1:

```
add_action( 'clear_auth_cookie', 'mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck', 10,0); <<<< ADD THIS INSTEAD
///add_action( 'wp_logout', 'mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck', 10,0);   <<<<< REMOVE THIS

function mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck()
{
$current_user  = wp_get_current_user(); 
if ( in_array( 'judge', (array) $current_user->roles ) )  
  {  
    mmd_StoreJudgeStatus($current_user->user_email, JUDGE_LOGGED_OUT, 0);  
  } 
}
```

SOLUTION 2: BETTER. As it does not interfere with woocommerce logout functionality.

```
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck', 10,1);  <<< NOTE PASSING 1 PARAMETER
function mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck($user_id)
{
$current_user  = get_userdata($user_id);

if ( (in_array( 'judge', (array) $current_user->roles )) 
  {
    mmd_StoreJudgeStatus($current_user->user_email, JUDGE_LOGGED_OUT, 0);  
  } 
}
```

Comment: Your function name is missing quotes, this code will generate PHP Fatal errors

Comment: Well it is not.  And if you look at how I defined the CONSTANT it passes the correct value.  It is in use as we speak. No errors.