# Getting User email on logout. wp_logout

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, logout

I have looked at a couple of different ways to check when a user, of a particular role, has logged out.  The call is made within a plugin.

In the main loop I have the following:

```
add_action( 'wp_logout', mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck, 10,0);

function mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck()
{
$current_user  = wp_get_current_user(); 
if ( in_array( 'judge', (array) $current_user->roles ) )  
  {  
    mmd_StoreJudgeStatus($current_user->user_email, JUDGE_LOGGED_OUT, 0);  
  } 
}
```

Each time the call to the wp_get_current_user returns a blank. That email is key to my functionality. I also tried

```
add_action( 'wp_logout', function() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck($user);
    // ...
}, 10, 0);

function mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck($current_user  )
{
if ( in_array( 'judge', (array) $current_user->roles ) )  
  {  
    mmd_StoreJudgeStatus($current_user->user_email, JUDGE_LOGGED_OUT, 0);  
  } 
}
```

Same results.  Calls that happen earlier do not appear to have user information.  Any assistance with how to get which particular user is logging out, would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**wp_get_current_user()** will never work in this hook, because, `wp_logout` action fires after user is logged out: session destroyed, cookies cleared and current user is set to 0.

But `wp_logout` action recieves $user_id. I will give you a working example, because I do not familiar with your custom functions.

```
//pass $user_id as argument
function mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck($user_id)
{
    $user  = get_userdata($user_id); 
    if ( $user instanceof WP_User  )  
    {  
        //user email available here
        die($user->user_email);  
    } 
}

//here last argument should be one
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck', 10,1);
```

Comment: Interesting.  I can look at that as well.   I found the clear_auth_cookie cookie call, carried the information. Thanks

Comment: Like wp_logout action more, because on this stage everything is cleared on 100% = user is logged out.

Comment: For grins, I tried it.  YUP, that worked too and does not interfere with woo commerce as well.  Great suggestion.

Comment: Accept my answer or your (if you can) as right answer, please. It will be removed from unanswered section, so we can help other people more efficiently. thanks =)

Comment: I already accepted your answer

Comment: Guess there should be a check sign. Arrows is for "useful" rating))

Answer (score -1):

Would you not know it, the minute I wrote the question, I thought of another idea and it worked.  Here is the solution:

In the plugin main, add the following INSTEAD OF :

```
add_action( 'clear_auth_cookie', mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck, 10,0); <<<< ADD THIS INSTEAD
///add_action( 'wp_logout', mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck, 10,0);   <<<<< REMOVE THIS

function mmd_JudgeLogoutCheck()
{
$current_user  = wp_get_current_user(); 
if ( in_array( 'judge', (array) $current_user->roles ) )  
  {  
    mmd_StoreJudgeStatus($current_user->user_email, JUDGE_LOGGED_OUT, 0);  
  } 
}
```

Appears that clearing the authorization cookie, carries the user information with it.